# Entity Framework & MySQL - BLOB/TEXT column used in Key without a key length

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

My problem:
Using Entity Framework with MySQL, I kept getting the error "BLOB/TEXT used in key specification without a key length". 
I added [StringLength(20)] and [MaxLength(20)] and [Column(TypeName="nvarchar")] to my only string-type [Key], with no progress.

I've found other references to this problem, but they are all out-of-date; there were issues in Connector/Net a few years ago related to this which have since been fixed.

Comment: I found this question while searching for how to get a MySql TEXT column generated at all with Code First. Could you post some sample code?

Comment: The solution for me was changing column type from text to varchar(64).  I posted an actual answer but we have trigger happy mods deleting them.

Answer (score 2):

The eventual solution:
It was not a [Key] problem at all, despite the error message.

I had used [Index] on some columns which were string-types too, and unlike columns with the [Key] attribute, EF does not automagically set these to an nvarchar type of limited length.
Decorate those columns with the attribute [MaxLength(255)], and MySQL is happy.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's solution of setting [MaxLength(255)] attribute does not seem to work with EF Core.  I was able to fix the problem by modifying column type from `text` to `varchar(255)`.